# How to convert buffer to string

Tags: autohotkey

I use two keyboard layouts (two languages) and for a scripting I'm writing, I need to get the current keyboard layout.

I found this function called `GetKeyboardLayoutNameA` from the `user32.dll`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayoutnamea

It only accepts one parameter and it points to the buffer of where the locale identifier is stored at:

> The buffer (of at least KL_NAMELENGTH characters in length) that receives the name of the input locale identifier, including the terminating null character. This will be a copy of the string provided to the LoadKeyboardLayout function, unless layout substitution took place.

So I wrote this script, and I used `StrGet` to convert the buffer to String, which seems to not work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
F7::
    VarSetCapacity(LocaleID, 8, 0)
    DllCall("GetKeyboardLayoutNameA", "Str", LocaleID)
    MsgBox, % LocaleID
    clipboard := StrGet(LocaleID)
Return
```

The script is just an example, my question is:

**How to access a data buffer, and get it's value?**

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `StrGet` and it would work fine. `StrGet` takes an address parameter:

> The address at which the string will be written to/read from.

But `LocaleID` isn't an address.

---

Additionally, you can use this to get the `LocaleID` of the keyboard:

```
F7::
 SetFormat, Integer, H
 WinGet, WinID,, A
 ThreadID:=DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "UInt", WinID, "UInt", 0)
 LocaleID:=DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", ThreadID, "UInt")
 MsgBox, %LocaleID%
 clipboard := LocaleID
Return
```

List of keyboard identifiers(thought would be helpful):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/dn938363(v=vs.94)

Comment: I did not use that script in the first place because it does not work on some windows like console window https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/43043-get-current-keyboard-layout/